# equation between datagrid cells

Tags: mysql, wpf, datagrid

I'm making inventory management program so i have this datagrid

```
+==========+==========+==========+==========+
|    C1    |    C2    |    C3    |    C4    |
+==========+==========+==========+==========+
```

In Start C1 and C2 are filled from MySQL, C3 and C4 are filled with ziros.
 Whene user change C3 value the programme fill C4 with this equation (C4 = C3 * C2).
 i'm using a UserControl (can use only System.Windows.Controls events).

I have no idea how to start doing this

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far. Datagrid and also your class which contains these 4 parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this behavior by `Data Binding` and `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

First you have to make a class that has four attributes (In your case, C1, C2, C3, C4).

Try something like this.

```
public class MyClass
{
  public MyClass(int c1, int c2)
  {
     C1 = c1;
     C2 = c2;
     C3 = 0;
  }

  private int c1, c2, c3, c4;

  public int C1
  {
     get { return c1;}
     set { c1 = value; }
  }

  public int C2
  {
     get { return c2;}
     set { c2 = value; }
  }

  public int C3
  {
     get { return c3;}
     set { c3 = value; }
  }

  public int C4
  {
     get { return C3 * C2;}
  }
}
```

Now if you look at the class, I have made a constructor that will receive two paramters `c1` and `c2` (Your DB values) and `C1` and `C2` are initialized with those values. And `C3` is initialized to 0. `C4` has only a getter that returns product of `C3` and `C2`.

Now to handle your scenario that when you change in `C3`, `C4` is automatically updated with the product of `C3` and `C2`, You need to `INotifyPropertyChanged`

[INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public MyClass(int c1, int c2)
  {
     C1 = c1;
     C2 = c2;
     C3 = 0;
  }

  private int c1, c2, c3, c4;

  public int C1
  {
     get { return c1;}
     set { c1 = value; }
  }

  public int C2
  {
     get { return c2;}
     set { c2 = value; }
  }

  public int C3
  {
     get { return c3;}
     set { c3 = value; }
  }

  public int C4
  {
     get { return C3 * C2;}
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
  {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
  }
}
```

In your code-behind, use an **ObservableCollection** of type `MyClass` and populate it with your DB.

```
ObservableCollection<MyClass> dbCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();

ObservableCollection<MyClass> DbCollection 
{
   get { return dbCollection; }
   set { dbCollection = value; }
}
```

Populate this collection with your DB data.

Now you have to set the `DataContext` for the `Window` to be the `Window` itself.

In `Constructor` of the `Window`, After `InitializeComponents()`, put `this.DataContext = this;`

Now for data binding 
Edit your Datagrid to do something like this.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource={Binding DbCollection}>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding C1, UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding C2, UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"}"></DataGridTextColumn>    
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding C3, UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding C4, UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"}"></DataGridTextColumn>
</DataGrid>
```

Now you have bound the Datagrid with your Collection. But still there is one piece of the puzzle missing. That is Notify the targets of the bindings (in this case, DataGridTextColumn) about the changes in source properties.

For that you have to edit the properties of MyClass class

```
public int C1
  {
     get { return c1;}
     set { c1 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("C1"); }
  }

  public int C2
  {
     get { return c2;}
     set { c2 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("C2"); NotifyPropertyChanged("C4");}
  }

  public int C3
  {
     get { return c3;}
     set { c3 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("C3"); NotifyPropertyChanged("C4");}
  }

  public int C4
  {
     get { return C3 * C2;}
  }
```

As you can see the change in parameter `c1` only notifies property `C1` but for `c2` and `c3` we notify `C4` as well because `C4` is product of `C3` and `C2`. It means `C4` needs to change whenever either of `C2` and `C3` is changed.

I know it is a lot to digest maybe at the start but it is a complete solution. Confident that it will solve your issue. Questions are welcome.

Comment: i don't get the part where do i have to populate the Collection with my DB, and where do i fill the DataGrid exactly here

Comment: In Start C1 and C2 are filled from MySQL
I assumed from this statement that you know how to populate this list from DB. You can do that by creating objects of MyClass and adding them to DBCollection List in code. The DataGrid population part is done for you automatically when you bind the DBCollection List to Datagrid.

Comment: i did this but keep get an error
    
    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        MyClass ob = new MyClass(row["C1"].ToString(),Convert.ToInt32(row["C2"].ToString()));
        DbCollection.Add(ob);
    }
The Error:
>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: row["C1"]. Here C1 represents the column name of your database and not the class' property. Are you sure ?

Comment: yes i'm sure, i verefied ob is not null and got tthe infos i need, but DbCollection is the null

Comment: I have edited my answer. The problem was not initializing the ObservableCollection. It was by default null obviously

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122109/discussion-between-umair-farooq-and-klaus).

Comment: the NullExeption has gone but the DataGrid still empty

Comment: I have edited the answer. When binding to some control, you have specify the DataContext of the window as well. See my edited answer now for DataContext

Comment: stull the same, DataGrid is empty